# Accelerometer detecting side to side movements

Tags: iphone, accelerometer

can someone please give me an example of how you detect if the iphone is moving left or moving right. like a long version of a shake i want my app to be able to know if the users arm is going right or left. imagine your hand like a window wiper with the phone at the end

any ideas?

Thanks, Sam :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be the acceleration.x value. Imagine 3 lines going through your iPhone: 
1) a line perpendicular to your iPhone screen and going through it, that would be Z. 
2) a horizontal and parallel line to your screen, that would be X (what you're looking for). 
3) a vertical and parallel line to your screen, that would be Y.

So, moving the iPhone left or right will generate changes in the X graph. Moving the iPhone up or down will generate changes in the Y graph. Moving your iPhone forward or backward will generate changes in the Z graph.

Hope this helps you grasp the accelerometer's concept, 
~ Natanavra.